# Error when trying to catch exception on psycopg2 (only with py2exe)

Tags: python, psycopg2, py2exe

I'm having some problems with this code:

```
...
query = f"INSERT INTO nichos VALUES {parameters}"
try:
    run_query(query)
    print()
    print("Nicho agregado exitosamente.")
    print()
    if ret == 1:
        return cod_nicho
except sql.errors.UniqueViolation:
    print()
    print("         ERROR. El nicho ya se encuentra cargado en el sistema. No se realizaron cambios en el registro.")
    if ret == 0:
        return
    elif ret == 1:
        return cod_nicho
except:
    log_error()
    print("")
    input("         ERROR. Comuníquese con el administrador...  Presione enter para continuar...")
    if ret == 0:
        return
    elif ret == 1:
        return cod_nicho
...
```

The thing is, when I execute it from Windows console ($ py script.py) it works perfectly, if you try to insert an existing value on database it execute the `except` block.

However, if I do the same from the .exe created with `py2exe` it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "funciones_mantenimiento.pyc", line 1459, in alta_nicho
  File "funciones_mantenimiento.pyc", line 160, in run_query
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «sqlite_autoindex_nichos_1»
DETAIL:  Ya existe la llave (codigo)=(0202010036).


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ventas.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "funciones_ventas.pyc", line 383, in menu
  File "funciones_ventas.pyc", line 1628, in menu_editar_op
  File "funciones_ventas.pyc", line 1823, in cambiar_nicho
  File "funciones_mantenimiento.pyc", line 1465, in alta_nicho
AttributeError: module 'psycopg2' has no attribute 'errors'
```

Somebody knows how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: An explicit `import` for a dependency that py2exe otherwise doesn't detect is a very usual workaround.

Comment: So, you're saying that I sould import the error? Like from psycopg2 import errors?

Comment: `import psycopg2.errors`, rather (if it were just a member instead of a separate module you wouldn't have this problem in the first place).

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy , I tried it and it works excelent...

Comment: **Do not use `f` strings** for passing in parameters. See here [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for correct and safe way to do this.

Comment: Glad that works; adding it as an answer so you can accept it to mark the question solved.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver for the observation 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that py2exe isn't correctly detecting that `psycopg2.errors` is a dependency of your program.

To make that easier for it to determine, add the following line:

```
import psycopg2.errors
```